# Slow performance on using parameters in linq-to-entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have a problem with a very slow (order of minutes!) query generated by Linq2Entities. The Linq query looks like this:

```
        var i = new IncludeStrategy<DeviceData>();
        if (includeIOData)
        {
            i.Include<DeviceDataExtended>(dd => dd.Extended);
        }

        var data = from dd in GetAllData()
                   where dd.DeviceId == deviceId
                   select dd;

        data = data.Include(i);

        data = data.OrderByDescending(dd => dd.UtcTime);

        if (start.HasValue)
        {
            var utcStart = start.Value.ToUniversalTime();
            data = data.Where(dd => dd.UtcTime >= utcStart);
        }
        if (end.HasValue)
        {
            var utcEnd = end.Value.ToUniversalTime();
            data = data.Where(dd => dd.UtcTime <= utcEnd);
        }

        return data.Skip(0).Take(15);
```

To test the query, I inspected the generated SQL output, and tried it directly in SQL Management studio - and lo and behold, it only took a couple of seconds. The generated SQL output from linq looks like this:

```
declare @p__linq__0 int = 15386
declare @p__linq__1 datetime2(7) = convert(datetime2, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121)
declare @p__linq__2 datetime2(7) = convert(datetime2, '2014-06-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121)

SELECT TOP (15) [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Project1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Project1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Project1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Project1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Project1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Project1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Project1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Project1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Project1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Project1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], [Project1].[IOData] AS [IOData]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Project1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Project1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Project1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Project1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Project1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Project1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Project1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Project1].[IOData] AS [IOData], [Project1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Project1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Project1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[UtcTime] DESC) AS [row_number]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Extent1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Extent1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Extent1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Extent1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Extent1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Extent1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Extent1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Extent1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Extent1].[IOData] AS [IOData], [Extent1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Extent1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Extent1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], 1 AS [C1]FROM [dbo].[DeviceData] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[DeviceId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[UtcTime] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[UtcTime] <= @p__linq__2)
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[UtcTime] DESC
```

There are 3 parameters: @p__linq__0, @p__linq__1 and @p__linq__2 representing deviceid, utcstart and utcend respectively.

After many attempts to modify the Linq query, I eventually found out that it must boil down to the linq parameters, because if I create the exact same query in Linq but replace the parameters with actual values - IT WORKS! This also explains why the query was fast in SQL Management Studio, because I naturally replaced the Linq parameters with actual values.

```
IQueryable<DeviceData> temp = from dd in ddRep.GetAll(i)
                              where dd.DeviceId == 15386 && dd.UtcTime >= new DateTime(2014, 05, 01) && dd.UtcTime <= new DateTime(2014, 06, 01)
                              orderby dd.UtcTime descending
                              select dd;

                return temp.Skip(0).Take(15);
```

The generated SQL output now looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (15) [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Project1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Project1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Project1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Project1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Project1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Project1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Project1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Project1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Project1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Project1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], [Project1].[IOData] AS [IOData]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Project1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Project1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Project1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Project1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Project1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Project1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Project1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Project1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Project1].[IOData] AS [IOData], [Project1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Project1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Project1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[UtcTime] DESC) AS [row_number]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], [Extent1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], [Extent1].[VehicleId] AS [VehicleId], [Extent1].[TokenId] AS [TokenId], [Extent1].[Latitude] AS [Latitude], [Extent1].[Longitude] AS [Longitude], [Extent1].[UtcTime] AS [UtcTime], [Extent1].[Speed] AS [Speed], [Extent1].[Heading] AS [Heading], [Extent1].[Satellites] AS [Satellites], [Extent1].[IOData] AS [IOData], [Extent1].[IgnitionState] AS [IgnitionState], [Extent1].[UserInput] AS [UserInput], [Extent1].[CreateTimeUtc] AS [CreateTimeUtc], 1 AS [C1]FROM [dbo].[DeviceData] AS [Extent1] 
        WHERE (15386 = [Extent1].[DeviceId]) AND ([Extent1].[UtcTime] >= convert(datetime2, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121)) AND ([Extent1].[UtcTime] <= convert(datetime2, '2014-06-01 00:00:00.0000000', 121))
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[UtcTime] DESC
```

The only difference between the two queries is the WHERE clause.

So what's going on here? Why is it so expensive to have parameters in Linq queries, and is the any way around it (and still sticking with EF)?

**EDIT:**
After more investigation, I found out that it boils down to whether the utcEnd parameter is a nullable datetime or not. If it *is* nullable, the query results in a CAST, and good performance - utcStart has no effect. Fortunately it is very easy to just cast it to a nullable datetime, but I'm still qurious as to why that would affect performance? The query hits an index on DeviceId (asc) - UtcTime (asc).

**EDIT 2:**
After looking at the actual execution plan, I can see that the reason of the problem definitely has to do with the fact that the table is partioned. The bad query makes a clustered index seek and joins EVERY table in the view (which is more than 200 tables!), which the good query only seeks and joins the tables covering the period between UtcStart and -End.

[image: Bad query]

[image: Good query]

So why are the parametized datetimes causing this horrible execution plan? I realize now that it's really an SQL Server question, rather than an EF question, so perhaps I should move it to dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This is a parameter sniffing problem. Search for that. Has been solved 100s of times.

Comment: @usr Thanks again for joining again - you really helped a bunch last time. I will definitely look into parameter sniffing :)

Comment: If this question is still relevant to you: The way to find out *why* something performs the way it does it to look at the actual execution plan. If you post the queries and plans you want to compare I'll answer what I notice about them.

Comment: As long as I cast the datetime to a nullable type, everything is fine - but I still would like to figure out why it's behaving so badly otherwise, and how to fix it. I have added screenshots of the two executions plans.

Comment: When you specify parameter values SQL Server uses the constraints on the tables in the query to remove table accesses that will always return zero rows. When parameters are used a plan is created that works for all possible inputs. I cannot tell from the images why the parameterized plan is that much slower. I understand you date predicate should lead to zero rows returned from most of the partition accesses, right? Seeking into 200 indexes and returning zero rows each should be cheap. So there's something going on that I could only tell from the XML plan. Upload it somewhere if you care.

Comment: Consider creating an index that is ideal for this query on each of the partitions. The index should include all columns that you need. That allows you to get rid of all sorting and key lookup operators. The speed gains from this can range from nothing to 100x or so. This can also help with plan quality in general because now there is clearly an optimal plan.

Comment: The table is partitioned into weeks, so all tables outside the datetime range will not return any rows. We have excluded the IO data column from all the indexes, because it's a varbin(100) field, and we were unsure how much extra space it would occupy. I have uploaded the XML plan here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PHdeCtlVj3ZEQ4VF9RdkVobkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. I suggest testing that index and observing its size. The index would be on (DeviceId, UtcTime DESC) INCLUDE(all other columns referenced). If that index doesn't help post the new plan as XML. Btw, are you aware that the partitions are inconsistently indexed? For some of the partitions there is a key lookup and for some there is none.; I was unable to find out why this query would take minutes. Just to make sure: The exact query that you ran to obtain the XML plan took a long time?

Comment: When a partitioned view starts to have >128 tables some optimizations are switched off. Consider partitioning on a larger time scale or not partitioning at all (why are you partitioning in the first place? To age out old data?).

Comment: We partition it to age out old data, and keep the current table (current week) a manageable size. We insert around 5 mio GPS coordinates daily, so in a week it grows to >32 mio rows and ~15 GB. We also have a very limited window for downtime (to avoid data loss). 
Oddly, everything seems to work much better now, I'm not sure why... The parametized query is still a bit slower, but only 7-8 sec. I can see from the execution plan that Number of Executions is 0 on all old tables.

Comment: It's a good point a about the 128 tables in index - we could probably have a greater range on older data instead of a week. About including the missing column - is there a way to estimate the amount of space required to include a column in an index?

Comment: If you have to you can estimate it. Make yourself familiar with the row format. For example, an int will take about 4 bytes of space. An nvarchar generally 4+2n bytes. And so on. Many edge cases there but you can probably ignore most of them.